# Laravel 8: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Rule' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my project, and I have made a Resource Controller under the `Admin` directory, which goes like this:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email',
            'max:255', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)],
    ]);

    if (!is_null($request->password)) {
        $request->validate([
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);

        $data['password'] = $request->password;
    }

    $user->update($data);

    if ($request->has('verify')) {
        $user->markEmailAsVerified();
    }

    return redirect(route('admin.users.index'));
}
```

As you can see, I put the method `update` because it holds some form of validation. But whenever I try to update the data within the form of the Blade file, I get this error:

> Error
> **Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Rule' not found**

I even tried adding `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;` but still receives the error. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call this in your file

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
```

Comment: i think i should be "use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;"